# Get row in TableView DevExpress

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, row, tableview

How can I get whole row values by clicking on it in DevExpress TableView? I tried to get row handle `tableView1.GetRowHandleByMouseEventArgs()` but it didn't work =(

**That's how I solved my problem:**

```
private void tableView1_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           var p = (e.NewRow as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the handle of a row located under the mouse pointer, use the [TableView.GetRowHandleByMouseEventArgs](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_GetRowHandleByMouseEventArgstopic) method.
To obtain a row object that corresponds to a row with the specified handle, use the [GridControl.GetRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_GetRowtopic) method. To get value from the specific cell, use the [GridControl.GetCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_GetCellValuetopic) method:

```
void TableView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    int rowHandle = grid.View.GetRowHandleByMouseEventArgs(e);
    object wholeRowObject = grid.GetRow(rowHandle);
    object rowId = grid.GetCellValue(rowHandle, "Id");   // cell value of row-object's Id property 
}
```

Related help-articles:
 - [Obtaining Row Handles](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6322)
 - [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6150)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass EventArgs as parameter like this:

MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs = o as MouseEventArgs;

```
        int rowHandle = tableview1.GetRowHandleByMouseEventArgs(mouseEventArgs);
```